# Flag mail with sieve to make them appear colored in MUA

Tags: sieve

I want to flag mails with sieve to make them appear colored in MUA.

Use case: On a very high traffic technical mailing list, there is a community member with a brilliant mind. I want to highlight his posts to make them more visible.

I want to do this with sieve (and not in the MUA) since I use different MUAs.

The result should look like this screen shot of thunderbird:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use sieve like this:

```
require "imap4flags";

if header :contains "from" ["malcolmt"] {
   addflag "$label5";
}
```

Here is the list of available hard-coded tags:

```
0 – Remove all tags,
1 – Important,
2 – Work,
3 – Personal,
4 – To Do,
5 – Later
```

List of flags is from [http://www.grimeton.com](http://www.grimeton.com/custom-tags-with-thunderbird-stored-on-imap-server/)

BTW, I choose 5 because I like the color. I don't care for the meaning in this context.